# How do i change the language for spellchecking in Libreoffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have to create a table with LibeOffice Calc in another language than my native one.

If I run the spellchecking, I manually have to change the language for every word in the document. How do I change it for the whole document at once?

I tried to select the desired language in the Extra/Auto Correction Options menu, which had no effect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to LibreOffice Help and a quick check on an existing Calc document.

> Choose Tools - Options. Go to Language Settings - Languages.
>
> Under Default languages for documents, select the document language for all newly created documents. If you mark For the current document only, your choice will only apply to the current document. Close the dialog with OK.

[image: screenshot with highlighting of 'this file only' setting]

Comment: However there may be some surprising side effects like https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104089

Comment: @U.Windl However it is accepted as a bug and therefore, hopefully in the fullness of time, be fixed!